# How to get a value from a row that is next day in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, date

I am trying to get a value from another row which is "next day" data for each person. Let's say I have this example dataset:

```
import pandas as pd    
data= {'date' : [20210701, 20210703, 20210704, 20210703, 20210705, 20210705],
    'name': ['Dave', 'Dave', 'Dave', 'Sue', 'Sue', 'Ann'],
     'a' : [1,0,1,1,1,0]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y%m%d')
```

I am trying to create another column with a value of column 'a' of the next day.

So, I created a 'next_day' column with:

```
df['next_date'] = df['date'] + pd.Timedelta(days=1)
```

but I am stuck on the next step.

The final data frame should look like this:

```
import pandas as pd    
data= {'date' : [20210701, 20210703, 20210704, 20210703, 20210704, 20210705],
    'name': ['Dave', 'Dave', 'Dave', 'Sue', 'Sue', 'Ann'],
     'a' : [1,0,1,1,1,0],
'new_column' : [np.nan, 1, np.nan, 1, np.nan, np.nan ]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y%m%d')
```

As you can see, the new column takes the value from the next day for each person and takes NaN for the ones that there is no data.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```py
        date  name  a  next_date
0 2021-07-01  Dave  1 2021-07-02
1 2021-07-03  Dave  0 2021-07-04
2 2021-07-04  Dave  1 2021-07-05
3 2021-07-03   Sue  1 2021-07-04
4 2021-07-05   Sue  1 2021-07-06
5 2021-07-05   Ann  0 2021-07-06
```

```py
df['next_date'] = df['next_date'].apply(lambda x:df.loc[df.date==x, 'a'])

        date  name  a  next_date
0 2021-07-01  Dave  1        NaN
1 2021-07-03  Dave  0        1.0
2 2021-07-04  Dave  1        NaN
3 2021-07-03   Sue  1        1.0
4 2021-07-05   Sue  1        NaN
5 2021-07-05   Ann  0        NaN
```

##### Update: Taking 'name' into account

Here is *a* solution – In order to account for the name as well, we can apply a function to the dataframe as a whole. As it's more complex, define it first,

```py
def get_next_a(x):
    # get the relevant rows
    values = df.loc[(df['name']==x['name']) & (df.date==x.next_date), 'a']

    # return the first truthy value or np.nan if no match is found
    return next((v for v in values), np.nan)
```

and apply it afterwards:

```py
df['new_column'] = df.apply(get_next_a, axis=1)
```

Comment: I think it does not take "name" column into account. I will play little more with your answer to get the names into play

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize numpy where to check for the wanted conditions and df.shift to grab next row values:

```
df['new_column'] = np.where(((df['name'].shift(-1)==df['name']) & 
                      (df['next_date']==df['date'].shift(-1))), df['a'].shift(-1), np.nan)
```